# Accessing a property required by an interface in a derived class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface

Assuming a base class of "Dog"...

```
Public Class Dog
  Public Property Breed as String
  Public Property Weight as Integer
End Class
```

Then, assume there are two possible interfaces that Dog can implement...

```
Public Interface iGuardDog
  Property PatrolRange  as Integer
  Property BarkVolume as Integer
End Interface


Public Interface iPlayfulDog
  Property RunSpeed as Integer
  Property FrisbeeSkill as Integer
End Interface
```

Then I define two classes that derive from Dog...

```
Public Class Shepherd
  Inherits Dog
  Implements iGuardDog
End Class

Public Class Poodle
  Inherits Dog
  Implements iPlayfulDog
End Class
```

So, I have a List(Of Dog) and add some Shepherds and Poodles to it.  Now I want to find the Guard Dogs and check their patrol range...

```
For Each D as Dog in MyDogs.Where(Function(x) TypeOf x is iGuardDog)
  debug.Writeline(D.PatrolRange)   '' This line throws an exception because it can't see the PatrolRange property
Next
```

What's the proper way to accomplish what I want to do?  I don't have a GuardDog base class; just an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the extension method [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913.aspx) on `IEnumerable`:

```
For Each d As iGuardDog In MyDocs.OfType(Of iGuardDog)()
    Debug.WriteLine(d.PatrolRange)
Next
```

This method does:

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

Thus it will only take the elements that implement your interface `iGuardDog`.

PS: in .NET you normally prefix interfaces with a capital "i" (so your interface would be IGuardDog). See also the [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!  Also thanks for pointing out the interface naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast each dog as `IGuardDog` Type. It will only give you access to the properties of IGuardDog and not those of the base `Dog` class, but you'd have those in your `D` variable:

```
Dim thisDog As iGuardDog
For Each D As Dog In MyDogs.Where(Function(x) TypeOf x Is iGuardDog)
    thisDog = CType(D, iGuardDog)
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("wt: {0}, range: {1}",
                                  D.Weight.ToString, thisDog.PatrolRange.ToString))
Next
```